# Random forest in sklearn

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I was trying to fit a random forest model using the random forest classifier package from sklearn. However, my data set consists of columns with string values ('country'). The random forest classifier here does not take string values. It needs numerical values for all the features. I thought of getting some dummy variables in place of such columns. But, I am confused as to how will the feature importance plot now look like. There will be variables like country_India, country_usa etc.  How can get the consolidated importance of the country variable as I would get if I had done my analysis using R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to do it by hand. There is no support in sklearn for mapping classifier specific methods through inverse transform of feature mappings.  R is calculating importances based on multi-valued splits (as @Soren explained) - when using scikit-learn you are limtied to binary splits and you have to approximate actual importance. One of the simpliest solutions (although biased) is to store which features are actually binary encodings of your categorical variable and sum these resulting elements from feature importance vector. This will not be fully justified from mathematical perspective, but the simpliest thing to do to get some rough estimate. To do it correctly you should reimplement feature importance from scratch, and simply during calculation "for how many samples the feature is active during classification", you would have to use your mapping to correctly asses each sample only once to the actual feature (as adding dummy importances will count each dummy variable on the classification path, and you want to do min(1, #dummy on path) instead).

Comment: okay. Thank you so much. I was not not sure if I can simply add the importance values for the dummy variables.

Comment: There is no clear way to do it, dealing with categorical variables through encoding always introduces some kind of bias. RF feature importance is more or less the expected fraction of points where this feature is used. Thus, if your feature is categorical, then each sample should only use a single dummy variable to get its value. And then you can simply add. Unfortunately, you do not control how many "other" dummy variables are used before finding the "valid" one (thus how many times you will have "not india", "not usa" before "russia") and consequently the aggregation is nearly impossible.

Comment: And by "impossible" I mean - impossible to recover from scikit-learn feature importances. It is still possible to calculate it by hand if you analyze each training/testing sample classification process, but this would require writing whole feature importance from scratch in your case, as you would like to only count "1"  no matter how many times during decision your dummy variables are used.

Comment: so, would you suggest going for R instead of sklearn when we need feature importance plot and we have string columns in the dataset?

Comment: Probably r is better choice for categorical data. Scikit learn is crafted for numerical ones

Comment: ok. Thank you. So, it seems that for any kind of algorithm using R would be better if there are string columns in the dataset.

Comment: "Probably R simply adds importance of all this artificial features" - No randomForest(R) natively supports splitting of multi-categorical features. So variable importance is computed in the same way for numerical and for categorical variables. Keep in mind the biases mentioned by Strobl et al: http://bmcbioinformatics.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2105-8-25

Answer (score 0):

A random enumeration(assigning some integer to each category) of the countries  will work quite well sometimes. Especially if categories are few and training set size is large. Sometimes better than one-hot encoding.

Some threads discussing the two options with sklearn:
https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/5442

[How to use dummy variable to represent categorical data in python scikit-learn random forest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15821751/how-to-use-dummy-variable-to-represent-categorical-data-in-python-scikit-learn-r)

You can also choose to use an RF algorithm that truly supports categorical data such as Arborist(python and R front end), extraTrees(R, Java, RF'isch) or randomForest(R). Why sklearn chose not to support categorical splits, I don't know. Perhaps convenience of implementation.

The number of possible categorical splits to try blows up after 10 categories and the search becomes slow and the splits may become greedy. Arborist and extraTrees will only try a limited selection of splits in each node.